# como crear un json de si mismo (this) en Python?

Tags: python, json, poo, objeto, data

Cordial saludo.

Necesito crear un Json de un objeto pero llamado desde si mismo self y que sea capaz de hacer un encode de todos sus atributos?

Supongase la clase persona: "Como creo un método que sea capaz de coger todos sus atributos y retornar un json?"

NOTA: la clase tiene casi 30 variables, lo que yo necesito es saber si se pueden hacerlas todas a la vez para no llenar un diccionario atributo por atributo.

```
from json import *

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id, sex, name, lastname, birthdate) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.sex = sex
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.birthdate = birthdate

    def getJson(self):
        """Return a Json model"""
        return JSONEncoder(self)



p = Person(0, "F", "Juanita", "Vargas", "01-07-2000")
print(p.getJson())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacer un `json.dumps()` pero primero necesitas pasar a un `dict`.

ejemplo:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id, sex, name, lastname, birthdate) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.sex = sex
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.birthdate = birthdate

    def getJson(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, 
            sort_keys=True, indent=4)



p = Person(0, "F", "Juanita", "Vargas", "01-07-2000")
print(p.getJson())
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esa era la respuesta correcta :)

Comment: Cuidado, dict contiene todos los atributos de la instancia, eso incluye aquellos que no se desean pasar al json. Probablemente sea conveniente crear un filtro.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque no es una respuesta de la pregunta, es posible que en este caso funcione mejor si se usa [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/dataclasses.html):

```py
import json
from datetime import date

import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int
    sex: str
    name: str
    lastname: str
    birthdate: date

    def to_json(self) -> str:
        dct = dataclasses.asdict(self)
        return json.dumps({k:str(v) for (k,v) in dct.items()})
```

Comment: Por que conviertes en cadena los valores?

Comment: El módulo json no es capaz de serializar objetos de tipo `date`. Como no quería complicar más el ejemplo, he preferido convertir todo con str para evitar errores y que se pueda ver un ejemplo que funcione. Sólo quería ilustrar una alternativa, no dar una respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo, aun así, en mi opinión es bueno aclararlo

Answer (score 1):

Las clases en Python ya tienen una función privada por defecto para devolver diccionarios, se llama [`object.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

```py
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id, sex, name, lastname, birthdate) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.sex = sex
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.birthdate = birthdate


p = Person(0, "F", "Juanita", "Vargas", "01-07-2000")
print(p.__dict__) 
# {'id': 0, 'sex': 'F', 'name': 'Juanita', 'lastname': 'Vargas', 'birthdate': '01-07-2000'}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :) no sabia eso <3