Como incluir un objeto dentro de una función que retona un Json en Python
Cordial saludo tengo una duda en python.
Tengo un objeto el cual utiliza el siguiente método para retornar un Json de sus atributos:
def get_json(self):
    return self.__dict__

pero tengo un problema cuando trato de añadir un objeto dentro de esta clase... el objeto deja de trabajar:
Este es el objeto que yo quiero imprimir en Json:
# app/models/person.py
from app.models.statistics import Statistics

class Person:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self._id = id
        self._first_name = ""
        self._middle_name = ""
        self._last_name = ""
        self._second_last_name = ""
        self._sex = ""
        self._age = 0
        self._location = ""
        self._plausible_death = ""
        self.statistics = Statistics()

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name

    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, value):
        self._first_name = value

    @property
    def middle_name(self):
        return self._middle_name

    @middle_name.setter
    def middle_name(self, value):
        self._middle_name = value

    @property
    def last_name(self):
        return self._last_name

    @last_name.setter
    def last_name(self, value):
        self._last_name = value

    @property
    def second_last_name(self):
        return self._second_last_name

    @second_last_name.setter
    def second_last_name(self, value):
        self._second_last_name = value

    @property
    def sex(self):
        return self._sex

    @sex.setter
    def sex(self, value):
        self._sex = value

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        self._age = value

    @property
    def location(self):
        return self._location

    @location.setter
    def location(self, value):
        self._location = value

    @property
    def plausible_death(self):
        return self._plausible_death

    @location.setter
    def plausible_death(self, value):
        self._plausible_death = value

    def get_json(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def __repr__(self):
        attributes = ', '.join(f'{key}={value}' for key, value in self.__dict__.items())
        return f'Person({attributes})'

Y este es el objeto que yo quiero añadir:
# app/models/statistics.py
class Statistics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.energy = 100  # 100 is full, 0 is exhausted
        self.hunger = 100  # 100 is full, 0 is starving
        self.intelligence = 50
        self.strength = 50
        self.mental_health = 70  # 100 is optimal, 0 is critical
        self.physical_health = 70  # 100 is optimal, 0 is critical
        self.social_skills = 50
        self.job_performance = 50

    def update_stat(self, stat_name, value):
        if hasattr(self, stat_name):
            new_value = getattr(self, stat_name) + value
            setattr(self, stat_name, max(0, min(new_value, 100)))  # Keeps stats within 0 to 100 range
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Statistic '{stat_name}' does not exist.")

    def get_json(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.get_json())

Alguien podria decirme que puedo hacer en el método get_json de person para poder retornar un Json interno de todo lo que hay en statistics.py
El problema consiste en que viene por parte de una respuesta de una API:
Este es el link del controlador:
https://github.com/felipedelosh/API-LifeInstructions/blob/main/app/controllers/player_controller.py
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es imprimir el player que es un hijo de Persona:
# app/models/player.py
from app.models.person import Person

class Player(Person):
    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__(id)
        self._father = None
        self._mother = None

    @property
    def father(self):
        return self._father

    @father.setter
    def father(self, value):
        self._father = value

    @property
    def mother(self):
        return self._mother

    @mother.setter
    def mother(self, value):
        self._mother = value

    def get_json(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def __repr__(self):
        attributes = ', '.join(f'{key}={value}' for key, value in self.__dict__.items())
        return f'Player({attributes})'


creo que esto ya fue respondido https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/602325/como-crear-un-json-de-si-mismo-this-en-python/602327#602327

Tienes que hacer lo siguiente:
Primero: aegurarnos de la existencia de get_json() en statistics.py
Segundo modificar el Player para agregar las estadisticas:
def get_json(self):
    json_data = {**self.__dict__}
    json_data['statistics'] = self.statistics.get_json()
    return json_data


Cuando hablamos de JSON nos referimos a texto o un archivo con un formato específico. JSON es un conjunto de reglas sobre cómo representar un objeto en un string.
Lo que haces con self.__dict__ es obtener el diccionario que representa tu clase. print muestra por consola el resultado de convertir los parámetros en string. En la conversión, a su vez, el diccionario convierte cada clave y valor en un string para obtener el resultado.
Puede que el string parezca tener el formato correcto, pero no. Para obtener el JSON de un objeto puedes utilizar la librería con el mismo nombre.
Esta librería te permite definir cómo quieres codificar tus propias clases, a través de la clase JSONEncoder. Por ejemplo, con tu código lo puedes así:
import json

class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        # Conviertes objetos en valores soportados, como diccionarios, listas, números, etc
        if isinstance(obj, Statistics) or isinstance(obj, Person):
            return obj.__dict__
        # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
        return super().default(obj)

print(json.dumps(Person(1), cls=Encoder))


Si lo que quieres es un diccionario, entonces puedes usar una función recursiva que se encargue de la conversión:
def get_dict(v):
    if type(v) in [bool, int, float, list, tuple, dict]:
        return v
    return {k: get_dict(v) for k, v in v.__dict__}

Incluso puedes crear una clase que de la que heredar, para no tener que repetir código:
class JSON:
    def get_json(self):
        return get_dict(self)

class Person(JSON):
    ...


Hola... Gracias por tu respuesta... pero actuamente estoy intentando implementar un contrato "Interfaz" para que todos mis objetos implementen un método get_json()... En el código de player agregar lo siguiente:
def get_json(self):
    json_data = {**self.__dict__}
    json_data['statistics'] = self.statistics.get_json()
    return json_data

La respuestá es más facil
